# "be obligated to do" versus "have to"

Tags: modality

Is it possible to say something like

> The employees were obligated to work in the previous weekend.

I deliberately didn't use ***have to*** in the sentence. So, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

I'd probably omit "***in***" when saying it, *or* used "***on*** *[the previous weekend]*". As to omitting "have to", it's correct because the obligation is already expressed.

> "... were obligated to have to work"

is superfluous.  Either they *had to work*, or *were obligated to work*.  Both essentially mean "forced by circumstances".  The circumstances can be a presence of some kind of agreement, promise, i.e. obligation.